# Axios как получить те же данные что и в fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios, fetch

Делаю запрос на один и тот же эндпоинт при помощи axios и fetch (тут имеется ввиду подключаемая либа в node.js а не вшитый функционал браузера).

Вариант с axios:

```
axios.get(someUrl)
   .then(res => {
       for (const key in res) {
           console.log(key);
       }
   });
```

Ответ:

```
status // 200
statusText // Ok
headers // все заголовки ответа одинаковые
config // параметры запроса axios
request
data // html
```

Вариант с fetch:

```
fetch.fetchUrl(someUrl, (error, meta, body) => {
    for (const key in meta) {
        console.log(key);
    }
});
```

Ответ:

```
status // 200
responseHeaders // все заголовки ответа одинаковые
finalUrl // !!!
redirectCount // 0
cookieJar
```

В ответе fetch по ключу `finalUrl` лежит ссылка которую и пытаюсь получить для дальнейшей работы. В html ее нет.

Можно ли получить эти данные средствами axios? Не хочется подключать на проект еще одну либу ради одного единственного запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в `res.request.res.responseUrl`

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/390

Comment: @eri спасибо большое, весьма полезная информация. никогда не заглядывал в .request.res а там много интересного. Но к сожалению в responseUrl лежит урл на который я делал изначальный запрос

Comment: @muturgan а в инспекторе редирект виден?